# would mysql js transaction pack up all instruction then commit in one time

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am a little bit confused when I use mysql js. I would like to figure out the actual mechanism behind the code.

As I know , if I would like to do a lot of mysql insertion which can run in parallel , it would be more efficient to pack all insertion instructions and commit to mysql one time.

My question is , I am using `promise-mysql.js`. I would like to use transaction to wrap the whole instructions like this

```
conn.beginTransaction()

einvoiceList.map(e => {
   conn.query("do some insertion")
})

conn.commit()
```

Am I correct to use this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an example using nodejs and mysql2 lib to handle multiple queries to the DB in parallel inside a transaction: https://github.com/Talento90/organization-api/blob/master/organizations-api/src/organizations/manager.js#L30

Basically the idea is to open a transaction and then do all the db queries and at the end commit or rollback the changes.

Tips: Try to use async/await it makes the job much easier :)

```
async myAsyncMethod(root) {
    let promises = [];
    let conn = null;

    try {
        conn = await this.database.getConnection();

        await conn.query('START TRANSACTION');

        //Execute multiple queries and save them inside an array to wait for the results later
        for(...){
           promises.push();
        }

        //Wait until all queries are done!
        let results = await Promise.all(promises);
        await conn.query('COMMIT');
        await conn.release();

        return results;
    } catch (error) {
        if (conn != null) {
            await conn.query('ROLLBACK');
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. My question is would mysql2 turn promises into one commit and send to mysql server?

Comment: Yes, promises array is just to keep track when all queries are done to the db because you just want to commit when all queries finish!

Sorry for the late answer! If this answer help you please mark as useful :)

Comment: no need for Promise.all - within one connection queries are executed sequentially (this is underlying protocol limitation). just `await` them one after another